# Does a KQQ vs KQ endgame position with perpetual check exist?

Tags: endgame, draw, queens, perpetual

In such an endgame situation (no specific position), where White isn't pinning the Black queen on the first move, is it possible for Black to get a perpetual check if they move first?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The position given by Akavall is indeed a [draw](https://syzygy-tables.info/?fen=5k2/1Q6/8/8/7q/8/7Q/7K_b_-_-_0_1) by perpetual, but it's a bit difficult to see because White has many different options at some moves. They can even choose to sacrifice the h2 queen, which effectively ends the perpetual (but it's still a draw).

A position where this is much easier to see is the [following one](https://syzygy-tables.info/?fen=5k2/8/8/8/8/5q2/7Q/6QK_w_-_-_0_1):

```
[FEN "5k2/8/8/8/8/5q2/7Q/6QK w - - 0 1"]

1. Qgg2 Qd1+ 2. Qhg1 Qh5+ 3. Q2h2 Qf3+
```

White has two options each move, and the black queen simply moves to the opened line/diagonal. As mentioned in the comments, White could sacrifice a queen on f1 or h3, but even then Black can force a perpetual on f1 and h3 (though the easiest way to draw is then trading the last pair of queens).

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it is possible. Here is an example:

```
[Variant "From Position"]
[FEN "5k2/1Q6/8/8/7q/8/8/6QK w - - 0 1"]

1. Qh2 Qe1+ 2. Kg2 Qe2+ 3. Kg3 Qe5+ 4. Kh3 Qh5+
5. Kg2 Qe2+
```